# Web Page Expired Exception

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application in which in the first page(Products Page) I have some filters or criterias based on which some products are displayed in a gridview.
The products are hyperlinked to another page which contains the details about that particular product(Details Page).

I click on a product and navigate to the Details page of that particular product and when I click on back to return back to my first page I am getting the expection:

“Web page has expired”.

Can you please tell me what could be the possible reason for this exception and how do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the expiry for the page is set to immediately.  How is your site being hosted where you are seeing this behavior.

Use a tool called fiddler to examine the "Expires" header in the response.  If the date/time is set to a date in the past then the browser shows the expires screen.

Note: fiddler needs tweaking to monitor site on localhost.

Comment: In the products page I have got some filters and a search textbox and a button on clicking this button some products are displayed on the Product page, I navigate to the details page by clicking on the link in the products page. 
The issue got solved when i added Response.CacheControl = "public" on my products page. 
But still I face this issue whenever I enter some text in the search text box and then navigate to the details page based on the search result?